# Long content scroll in one slide of `Swiper.js`

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I created a vertical swiper and it contains only one slide, which contains many lines. I want it to scroll down when I swiper it.

But the actual result is that after I scroll down, it scroll back to the top when my finger left the screen.

Demo is here: https://jsfiddle.net/v84f688o/2/

```
//html:
<body>

  <div class="msg-content-container swiper-container">
    <div class="msg-content-wrapper swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="msg-content-slide swiper-slide">
        <div class="msg-content">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="msg-content-swiper-scrollbar"></div>
  </div>
</body>
// js:
$('.msg-content').html('first line' +'<p>asdfsf</p>'.repeat(100));

var swiper = new Swiper('.msg-content-container',
{
    wrapperClass: 'msg-content-wrapper',
    slideClass: 'msg-content-slide',
    direction: 'vertical',
    width: 100,
    height: 200,
    scrollbar: '.msg-content-swiper-scrollbar',
    mouseswheelControl: true,
    freeMode: true
})
```

The `first line` is always on top no matter how I swipes.

Comment: Have you found an answer to this?

Comment: yes. It's a long time ago. My finally code is like the following:  `new Swiper('.' + name + '-content-container', {
        wrapperClass: name + '-content-wrapper',
        slideClass: name + '-content-slide',
        direction: 'vertical',
        scrollbar: '.' + name + '-content-swiper-scrollbar',
        slidesPerView: 'auto',
        mouseswheelControl: true,
        freeMode: true
      });`   It seems change the `width` and `height` to `slidesPerView: 'auto'` solves this. But I am not sure, you can try it, if it not work, I will run the project again and find the answer.